# Record click action and replay via command line?

Tags: macos, automator, automation, accessibility

Every few minutes I need to click a button on Yosemite's menu bar and select an option. I'd like to automate this task by somehow recording this action and scheduling it to execute via cron / command line.

I've tried creating an Automator workflow using the "Watch Me Do" feature, but although it executes fine inside Automator, when I run `automator myclicks.workflow` in the Terminal, it gives me this cryptic error message:

`The action encountered an error.`

How can I get automator action to work?

Comment: Welcome. I've edited this to have one question. If you want to ask a second question about [tag:software-recommendations] feel free to link here and explain you want an alternative to Automator. Also, please edit this to show the "cryptic" error message or upload a link to the photo (imgur works well)

Comment: Not sure how much help can be given without seeing the actual myclicks.workflow file, however do you get any more helpful output if you run with debugging enabled? E.g.:  `automator -debug myclicks.workflow`

Comment: @user3439894 the -debug didn't return anything meaningful, thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

So this might be an Accessibility issue. I was able to resolve it by going to System Preferences>Security & Privacy>Accessibility and then making sure Terminal had a check in the checkbox under Privacy.

This link does a great job of explaining it. [Automator in Terminal](http://dougscripts.com/itunes/2013/10/os-x-10-9-applescripts-and-accessibility-control/)

And by the way console can be very useful in getting meaningful error messages.

Hope this helped.